# Regular expression, match error

Tags: regex, replace, match

i just started with regular expressions and went into trouble by writing one for a case i would need.

Here is my problem. I wrote this simple regex:

```
(<img).+[>]
```

it match for the most cases, but not for the case if something is between.
Here is a image for you maybe this will explain my problem better:
[image]
There you can see it very well. It should select only the img-tag areas but not the 'a' between them.

Can somebody give me some advices how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post what ever is in that image? Parsing html/xml with regexs usually wont work out. The issue here might be that your regex is greedy currently so it selects everything until the last `>`. You also dont need the `>` in a character class. Also the language you are using this in would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispense with most of your pattern - much of it is unnecessary.

Try this:

```
<img.*?>
```

With the unnecessary brackets removed, the important change is adding `?` to make it a *reluctant* quantifier - one that matches as *little* as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` is greedy and will match as many characters as it can, so it is continuing to get characters after the first `>` because there is another one later on in the string that it can match without invalidating the other parts of the regex.

To prevent the `+` being greedy add a `?` after it.

```
(<img).+?[>]
```

Note that other elements of your regex are probably not necessary and it can be reduced to:

```
<img.+?>
```

(Since `[>]` is the same as `>`, and the `()` was a capture group that you weren't using)